# How to control kinect NUI Motor?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i want to control my motor and change the direction of it. how can i doing it?
i've tried [this one](http://csmartonline.com/blog/2012/03/27/kinect-motor-control/). but it doesn't work. i failed compile it, and failed run the .exe program. said that

> KinectMotor.cpp:2:19: fatal error: XnUSB.h: No such file or directory
> #include <XnUSB.h>

so, is there any option to do it with ROS?

i've heard there's something called kinect_aux package.
but, i don't have those package in openni_launch or openn_camera or libfreenect or blabla.
where can i find it?

Thank's for help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223228/how-to-control-kinect-nui-motor?/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, i've found the answer [in here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinect_aux) hehe

---

Originally posted by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) with karma: 76 on 2015-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1